# Problem with compiling header and cpp file on macOS Catalina in clang++

Tags: c++, gcc, unique-ptr, clang++, macos-catalina

I've been trying tu run this code but I'm keep getting this long error message. I think the code is okay, because it's working on my Windows computer, so I think it's a problem with my compiler. I am using VisualStudioCode on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and clang 12.0.0.

1. This is my main.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "Wezel.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    unique_ptr<Wezel>(new Wezel()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2. Wezel.cpp file

```
#include "Wezel.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Wezel::~Wezel() {
  cout << "Destruct" << endl;
}
```

3. Wezel.h file

```
#ifndef WEZEL_H
#define WEZEL_H

class Wezel
{
    public:
    ~Wezel();
};

#endif
```

4. The error message I get when I try to compile the main.cpp file

```
majkel@mbp-micha RecyclingCpp % cd "/Users/majkel/Documents/Obiektowe/RecyclingCpp/" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/majkel/Documents/Obiektowe/RecyclingCpp/"tempCodeRunnerFile
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Wezel::~Wezel()", referenced from:
      std::__1::default_delete<Wezel>::operator()(Wezel*) const in tempCodeRunnerFile-40bbc5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you seem to have many copies of your compile commands? are they all relevant?

Comment: ah yes, I guess I've totally messed something up... I've edited the error message

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell the compiler that `Wezel.cpp` was part of the thing you are trying to build, so it doesn't know where to find `Wezel::~Wezel()`.

Try like this:

```
g++ main.cpp Wezel.cpp
```